# add class to li by clicking on a link from nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, addition

I'm a newbie so i hope my question will have some logic :)

i wish to add a class "active" to "li" (in this case a portfolio filter item in the page) by clicking on a link from the nav menu.
the "li" is not a part of the nav menu, how do i assign a "li" with a class if the "li" is in the deep tree - it's a whole different part of my site.

```
the "li" is in:
<div class=""section"
<ul id="portfolio-filter" class="list-inline">
        <li <--- the place i wish the "active" be added
```

i have checked other question but couldn't figure out how to implement the specific need.
thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried the answer below - no luck there. ihave posted a new question with more details regarding this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176524/clicks-on-a-nav-menu-item-it-will-trigger-a-filter

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a listener for the link of the menu. In JQuery, to create a listener, you have the 'on' function.

Example :

```
$("myElement").on("click",function(){});
```

After that, add an id attribute for the 'li' tag.

For example:

```
<li id="myLI">
```

So, when the user will click on the link of the menu, it will go to the listener. And in the listener, you will do :

```
$("#myLI").addClass("active")
```

Don't forget to create the css class.

Comment: thank s for the answer, much appreciated. i have tried this option but it only set my li with active class regardless myElement on click... ihave created the css class. why is this happenning? any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you have to specify `.active` in your CSS.

```
.active {
//add styles here
}
```

Then using javascript you have to grab `#myLI` and set class `.active` to it using `onclick` event:

```
 var  element = document.getElementById("myLI");
 element.onclick = function() {
               element.setAttribute('class','active');
            }
```